# What is the speed of anti-ice bleed airflow in helicopter turboshaft engines?

Tags: helicopter, airspeed, anti-ice, bleed-air, turboshaft

If we consider the most modern turboshaft engines, what will the approximate speed for the bleed airflow when it's routed from the latter stages of the engine and supplied to the areas that require anti-icing. Apologies, if the question is a bit broad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Don't apologize for breaking the rules, [edit] your question to follow them.